# How to prevent wrapping my Router in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, router

Can some please help me out here, I wanted to prevent wrapping my Router with Settings map function for web app background.

With the way it is right now my app is running way too slow (In deploy mode it takes a while to load home page alone )

````
  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Context);
  const { settings } = state;
  window.scroll(0, 0);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <ToastContainer />
        {settings?.map((b, index) => (
          <div
            className="App s_flex"
            key={index}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${b.background})`,
              backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
            }}
          >
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />}></Route>
              <Route path="/:id/details" element={<ReviewScreen />}></Route>
              <Route path="/:id/download" element={<DownloadScreen />}></Route>
              <Route path="/about" element={<AboutScreen />}></Route>
              <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactScreen />}></Route>
              <Route path="/request" element={<RequestScreen />}></Route>
              <Route path="/disclaimer" element={<DisclaimerScreen />}></Route>
              <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyScreen />}></Route>
              <Route
                path="/fix-general-installation-errors"
                element={<GameErrorScreen />}
              ></Route>
            </Routes>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Settings is only for the background image?

Why not have several qualities of images that loads as the page loads?

Choosing different images based on screen size and optimize the image for the browser.

Create animations or conditional render certain elements if the user has 1mb download speed.

Consider the ux based on the user device and connection for a better experience